# Adsense Onclick(php, javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, adsense

I have tried to understand how to use a onclick for a adsense unit. Some say that this wont be possible and some say the opposite. What is correct ?

Is there anyway to get the onclick for a adsense unit. So when a adsense unit has been clicked, it will do something also.

Comment: I think it would be possible. Just not that easy.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff That only works because the iframe and the parent site are the same domain. Cross-domain restrictions are applied when you use AdSense.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Yeah, I found that when I tried it using it with another website. @Ukjent - Would you be able to overlay an invisible `<div>`?

Comment: An invisible div would intercept the clicks on the ads. Not good for revenue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. In order to prevent abuse, AdSense ads (and most major ad serving systems) run within an iframe specifically to isolate them from your page.

Comment: Ok, I need the onclick to: I have a custom google search with adsense for search. The site is set up like this: www.example.com/id="12345", and i want to let the different users see their adsense stats. Any solution for this ? Sry if its hard to understand what i try to say

Comment: No, you can't do that to my knowledge.